# How to change a variable after some time has passed?

Tags: ios, algorithm, swift, sprite-kit

Say I have several coins. When the user collects a coin, I want some variable to be set to true. Then after 10 seconds, the variable gets reset to false.

Say the user collects a coin. The variable is set to true. 6 seconds pass. In another 4, the variable would be reset to false. However, the user now collects another coin. Another 10 seconds should be added to the time. So now, the variable will be reset back to false in 14 seconds, instead of 4.

In other words, every time the user collects a coin while the variable is set to true, 10 seconds is added to the time currently remaining. The time "adds" on.

Could someone suggest how I can do this? I already have the code to detect when a coin is collected, but am having trouble with the rest. It seems very simple, but it has turned out to be quite a challenge.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
if coinCollected {
    //Execute this code every time a coin is collected

    timeBeforeVariableIsSetToFalse += 10

    if variableToBeReset == false {
       variableToBeReset = true

       runAction(
                 SKAction.runBlock({
                      while self.timeBeforeVariableIsSetToFalse > 0 {
                            self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1)))
                            self.timeBeforeVariableIsSetToFalse --
                      }

                      self.variableToBeReset = false
                 })
       )
    }
}
```

However, instead of waiting a second between each decrement of timeBeforeVariableIsSetToFalse, they all basically happen right after each other. It's as if `self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1)))` is being ignored.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I couldn't come up with a one that described the problem well. If you have any suggestions, I'll certainly change it.

Comment: Start by paying heed to [ask]: imagine yourself reading the question without prior knowledge of the problem or poster, and trying to make head or tail of it: in a list of titles, say, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm?sort=active&pagesize=23, does `How do I do this hard thing?` give as much information as others? (Please take more than one comment like this as another hint.)

Comment: @greybeard Well, the title is intentionally cryptic. When people see the question, the lack of information in the title makes it stand out, and the curiosity of people makes them want to click on it.

Comment: @adsf Their "curiosity" will also make them want to not answer your question

Comment: @adsf and you think that's a good thing?

Comment: @Alejandro Speaking from experience, that isn't true. Whatever, I changed it anyways. How's the title now?

Comment: @jasondinh Yes, why wouldn't it be? I want people to see my question, don't I?

Comment: Why the hell is my question being down voted?

Comment: My take: your question has been voted down for trolling: for the impression of wilfully annoying others on the 'net. Your question has become better: you added a run time environment (to the tags, where it might be overlooked more easily as in the question proper). The tile is not as bad as before - it might be good if it included a hint to the start of the time interval in question. (Your latest edit - the "thanks"-line - is not welcome here and might fall victim to the "citizen patrol".) - Look for ["watchdog (timer)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer).

Comment: @greybeard How am I trolling? This is a genuine question for a genuine problem I have. I've shown that I've tried stuff before asking and the question is completely relevant. This is a valid question in my opinion.

Comment: It is a valid question. You discuss what you are trying to do, what you've tried, and have code. The title got you some downvotes, take it as a lesson in the community culture. We (in the collective sense) are, apparently, pretty serious, right? Now you know, hopefully the next question gets a better title and a better reception. Reputation aside, you got at least one answer, maybe more. Hope you find a solution! (review posterity: did not vote to close)

Comment: Another part of internet culture: [Do not feed the trolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll)

Comment: @greybeard not constructive :/

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I would do:

Create two variables that are defined at the top of the class and are available to all routines.  One (`booHasCoin`) holds whether the player has picked up a coin or not (in case you want to animate a coin on the screen or something), and the other (`intCounter`) will hold the number of seconds before the coin variable gets set to false.

```
var intCounter:Int = Int()
var booHasCoin:Bool = Bool()
```

Every time your timer ticks (set it to tick once per second), make it run the following code:

```
if intCounter > 0 {
    intCounter -= 1
    booHasCoin = true
} else {
    booHasCoin = false
}
```

And every time the player picks up a coin, you just have to run the following code:

```
intCounter = 10
```

The timer is always ticking, and if the user has not picked up a coin, then `intCounter` will equal 0 and booHasCoin will equal false.  As soon as they pick up a coin, `intCounter` will equal 10 and each second it will decrease by one until, after 10 seconds, `intCounter = 0` and `booHasCoin` is set to `false`.

I hope this helps :).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this wouldn't work. Consider this scenario: the user collects his first coin. Immediately after the user collects it, the timer happens to tick, the code is executed and 1 is subtracted from intCounter. intCounter is now 9, even thought a second hasn't passed. My point is that in the worst case where the timer happens to tick right after the character collects a coin, 1 will be subtracted from the time even though a second hasn't passed. This solution will result in the program waiting for some time between 9 and 10 seconds, instead of 10.

Comment: Then you can have the timer inactive by default and when the user collects a coin, it triggers the timer, which goes about its business subtracting 1 until it runs out and the coin disappears.

Comment: Well, that's essentially what I'm doing in my solution above, but that doesn't seem to be working unfortunately.